# `/me` command in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

In essence, chat should have a `/me <string>` command.

How it works:

User pacificfils types `/me goes to get coffee`
Chat prints:

> **pacificfils** goes to get coffee

This would add a nice, simple, and fun feature to the chat that we already have.
@Mateo, I am referring to how IRC does it:

```
[11:59] <@pacificifls> This is a test
[12:00] * pacificifls does a test
```

So in AskUbuntu Chat, the name and message would all be where just the message is. There would be no icon.

Comment: I rather like it just plain-text best.

Comment: GOOD LORD PEOPLE! JUST AN IDEA!

Comment: And mine is just an opinion...

Comment: This was asked on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62979/me-command-for-chat), however it doesn't have a `status-*` tag yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have you name associated with your post, double posting you name looks strange

[image]

So "Mateo **Mateo** goes to get coffee" ~

---

Just use italics to suggest you are performing an action.

Comment: refer to edited post

Comment: This is what we've been doing for years without issue. Just use `*action that you're doing*`. If it really bothers you, you can write a greasemonkey script to do that for you

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: In fact, the [SE Chat Modifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat) script already [has that feature](http://rchern.github.io/StackExchangeScripts/readme.html): "*`/me <message>` - wraps the `<message>` in a pair of `*` to italicise it in a lame attempt at emulating IRC `/me`*"